# Linq2SQL check if item is null

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

foreach (var incident in new DataAccess.IncidentRepository().GetItems().Where(
                        i => (startDate == null || i.IncidentDate >= startDate)
                        && (endDate == null || i.IncidentDate <= endDate)
                        && (shiftId == null || i.ShiftId == shiftId)
                        && (processAreaId == null || i.ProcessAreaId == processAreaId)
                        && (plantId == null || i.PlantId == plantId)))

is there a way I can `i.PlantId == plantId` not to get added if `plantId` is `null`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
var incident in new DataAccess.IncidentRepository().GetItems().Where(
                    i => i.IncidentDate >= startDate 
                    && i.IncidentDate <= endDate 
                    && i.ShiftId == shiftId 
                    && i.ProcessAreaId == processAreaId
                    && (plantId == null || i.PlantId == plantId)))
```

Alternatively, you could:

```
var incidents = new DataAccess.IncidentRepository().GetItems().Where(
                    i => i.IncidentDate >= startDate 
                    && i.IncidentDate <= endDate 
                    && i.ShiftId == shiftId 
                    && i.ProcessAreaId == processAreaId));

if (plantId != null)
    incidents = incidents.Where(i => i.PlantId == plantId);

foreach (var incident in incidents) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: That makes no sense i.PlantId comes for the database plantId is the parameter passed into the method.

Comment: so basicly if plantId == null then i.PlantId should not be added to the where clause.

Comment: I added that option too. Both are effectively the same. Refresh to see.

Comment: in SQL I would do this

WHERE USerId = ISNULL(@UserId,UserId)

Comment: It should work. There's no problem in chaining Where clauses. They act like AND.

Comment: +1 for converting common SQL dynamic parameter "trick" into Linq. ;)

Comment: Thats where the problem comes in I will need to have like 50 if statements which is not what I wanted to do. I tought there might be a easy way

Comment: The first query is effectively like your `ISNULL` query. The second doesn't send the parameter to the server at all if it's null.

Comment: So choose the first option. It's the most succinct way out there.

Answer (score 0):

```
var incident in new DataAccess.IncidentRepository().GetItems().Where(
                    i => i.IncidentDate >= startDate 
                    && i.IncidentDate <= endDate 
                    && i.ShiftId == shiftId 
                    && i.ProcessAreaId == processAreaId
                    && object.Equals(i.PlantId, plantId)))
```